# coefficient $z^n$ in expansion of $e^zcosz$

Tags: sequences-and-series

find the coefficient of $z^n$ in expansion of $e^z \cos z$

my attempt:

I know the coefficient of $z^n$ in taylor expansion of f=$e^z \cos z$ about z=0 is $\frac{f^n(0)}{n!}$

nth deriative of f is needed so this way is tedious.

however the book goes by expanding coszcoshz + isinzsinhz = some infinite series .. is there such a way out?

Comment: $$e^z\cos z = \frac{1}{2}\bigl(e^{(1+i)z} + e^{(1-i)z}\bigr)$$

Comment: its tedious too . it gives (1/(2n!))((1+i)^n+(1-i)^n)

Comment: And if you write $$(1+i)^n = 2^{n/2}\cdot \biggl(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\biggr)^n\,?$$

Comment: Alternately, see [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).

Answer (score 1):

Too your comment about too tedious It most certainly not as
$$
\mathrm{e}^z\cos z = \mathcal{Re}\left(\mathrm{e}^z\mathrm{e}^{iz}\right) = \mathcal{Re}\left(\mathrm{e}^{(i+1)z}\right) =\mathcal{Re}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1+i)^kz^k}{k!}\right)
$$
so we have
$$
\mathcal{Re}\frac{(1+i)^n}{n!}=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{0\leq 2k\leq n}\left(\matrix{n\\k}\right)(-1)^k
$$
this is assuming that $z$ is Real.